# How to make db handle auto insert sequence id postgesql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, nativequery

I had an existed entity (TableEntity.java), the table existed in db, and also the data
Here is how the column id already delcared in TableEntity.java

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "table_name_id_seq", sequenceName = "table_name_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "table_name_id_seq")
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updateable = false)
private int id;
```

In the database, I look at the properties of the table, for id column, the data type is int and set as Not NULL
The previous code, for inserting data to db, is only doing "repository.save()"
But now, I want to use PreparedStatement to insert data to db per batch
Here is how I create the query

```
String query = "INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2) values (?, ?)";
```

the problem is, when the query executed, its violates null constraint for the id column. How to make the database can handle my column id? Since, when I just use repository.save() is work fine, but when I use that (could I say it a native query?) query, that exception appear. How to solve this? or any reference to solve this?

Comment: Are you looking for `id integer default nextval('table_name_id_seq')`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in short, I want to make the db handle by itself for create the id value for id column, but still using sequence. So, I dont have to mention "id" column in the String query above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a default value for the column:

```
alter table table_name
   alter column id set default nextval('table_name_id_seq');
```

Now if an INSERT statement does not supply a value for the `id` column (by not mentioning it), the next sequence value is used to populate the column.

Comment: Alrite, I'll try first. But, actually this is another question. If I want to make a new entity, how to set default value as the nextval of the sequence as the query above? I mean, how to set it in the TableEntity.java @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @Akza: sorry, no idea. I don't use JPA or Hibernate